# if and else - both are executing

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a simple question answer site, in which - I am trying to implement a like button But When i like the post then `solid liked button` is showing and `blank liked button` is also showing.

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title= models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Answer(models.Model):
    user_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    que = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class LikeAnswer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
def question_detail(request, question_id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)

    answers = obj.answer_set.all()

    context = {'obj':obj,'answers':answers}
    return render(request, 'question_detail.html', context)
```

quesion_detail.html

```
{{obj.title}}


    {% for anss in answers %}

        {% for lks in anss.likeanswer_set.all %}

            {% if request.user == lks.user %}

              <button name='submit' type='submit' id="unlike" value="unlike">Unlike
    </button> <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>

            {% else %}

              <button name='submit' type='submit' id="like" value="like">
    </button><i class="fal fa-thumbs-up"></i>

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}


    {% endfor %}
```

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to show only filled like button after user like, But it is showing both buttons.

- I have also tried `{% empty %}` but it didn't made impact on it, It showed same results.

**They are showing like :-**

[image]

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: I don't know django and whether it cares about indentation, but note that the `if`, `else` and `endif` are not indented consistently in your code.

Comment: *"not indented consistently"* Can you explain or point out, How ?

Comment: Maybe you should use css classes instead of the IDs (class="like" instead of id="like") since you will have multiple instances with the same ID if there are more than one answers

Comment: I'd consider creating a `ManyToMany` relationship between `Answer` and `User` and name it `liked`. Also print `{{ lks.id }}` before both buttons to verify that it's from a different object.

Comment: @Lars Well, you've edited your question and now the indentation is consistent

Comment: @Stef Indentation is not an issue with the Django Template Language.

Comment: @Lewis, I was using `ManyToManyField` and It was working fine, I didn't change any `ajax stuff`  , I just changed the `querying` (like models and views ) But i had to implement some other features. Answer is successfully liking and unlicking, Only problem is that like button

Comment: I think @Boketto's answer explains this issue. Since all likes are iterated, the  likes that are not from `request.user` will still be rendered. Try to remove the else part

Comment: @BrianD, Now it is not showing `solid like button`, It is only showing like button on answers which are already liked.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over *all* likes, whether they are from the request user or not, and as soon as there is *any* other user, there will be also the "unlike" button, so you will have both buttons.

Comment: But i have to use the for loop, So you mean i should use for loop from `view`  ? `or` i should use loop outside ?